# How to print string which is passed from 2d array using pointer to an array?

Tags: c, pointers

Hello How to print string which is passed from 2d array to function called print_2d and
in that  function i am catching base address of 2d array which has string as its element

now with pointer to an array now i want to print the string using pointer to an array? 
my code is below

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_2d(char (*p)[10],int r) // i am catching with pointer to an array
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    printf("%s",*p[i]); //segmentation fault why?
                            // how to print then?
}

main()
{
    char *s[10]={"one","two","three","four"};
    int r;
    r=sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
    print_2d(s,r);
}
```

Comment: Do you want a pointer to an array or an array of pointers?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice pointer to an array (*p)[10]?

Comment: But `s` is declared as an array of pointers...

Comment: Note that there is no 2D array present in the code shown.  There is an array of pointers, but that's a 1D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print_2d` function is declared as accepting a pointer to `char[10]` array. However, nowhere in your code there's a `char[10]` array. There's noting in your code that can be legally passed to `print_2d`.

Anyway, it is not possible to "fix" your code, until you explain what you are trying to do.

Judging by the body of `print_2d` and by what you have in `main`, you might need the following

```
void print_2d(char *(*p)[10],int r)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    printf("%s", (*p)[i]);
}

int main()
{
    char *s[10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    int r;
    r = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
    print_2d(&s, r);
}
```

Note that parameter `p` is declared as a pointer to an array of `char *` pointers, which is what your `s` in `main` is. However, you have to realize that pointer to array can only point to an array of *fixed pre-determined* size. The array passed to `print_2d` will always have size 10 and only 10. For this reason, it makes no sense to pass array size to `print_2d` separately. Just calculate the size inside and get rid of the second parameter

```
void print_2d(char *(*p)[10])
{
  int i, r;
  r = sizeof *p / sizeof **p;
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    printf("%s", (*p)[i]);
}

int main()
{
    char *s[10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    print_2d(&s);
}
```

Alternatively, your code can be fixed as shown in @BLUEPIXY's answer, but that is a completely different way to interpret your intent. And we don't know what your intent was.

Comment: thanks a lot from last few days i was search lot for the solution how to catch array of pointer with pointer to an array..finally i got thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_2d(char *p[10],int r) // This is another change.
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        printf("%s",p[i]); // This is the main change
}

int main() // main has to return int
{
    char *s[10]={"one","two","three","four"};
    int r;
    r=sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
    print_2d(s,r)
}
```

`s[0]`, `s[1]` etc are the strings. Why are you trying to print `*s[0]`, `*s[1]` etc?

Comment: sorry char*p[10] is an array of pointer actually i want to catch with  pointer to an array (*p)[10] and then print them?

Comment: @SumitKumar The "main change" is the important thing here. Because of the implicit conversion when passing a parameter, the difference between an array of pointers and a pointer to an array is probably irrelevant. (However, there might be other implications that aren't being addressed by this question.)

Comment: @SumitKumar - from `main` you are passing an array of pointers. Hence you should accept an array of pointers & not pointer to an array.

Comment: @user93353 that was only my question i was asked in an interview i have to catch array of pointer with pointer to an array?please can u explain is it possible i said him its not possible

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is `r = 10` every time. So when you pass `print_2d(s,r)` you are telling `print_2d` there are 10 strings to print. You cannot get the `r` using `sizeof (arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` it will return `10` each time. You have created a pointer to `10 character arrays` with your assignment and initialization (which null terminates the 4 given strings by default and leaving 6 empty). To prevent teh segfault, you need to pass the number of character arrays to `print_2d`. For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print_2d(char **p, int r) // i am catching with pointer to an array
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        printf ("%s\n", p[i]);
}

int main (void)
{
    char *s[10] = {"one","two","three","four"};
    int r;
    // r = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);  // r = 10 causing segfault @ i = 4 in print_2d
    // you cannot get the number of string arrays in this manner. 
    r = 4;
    printf("r: %d\n", r);
    print_2d (s,r);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/par
r: 4
one
two
three
four
```

If you want to use `sizeof (s) / sizeof (s[0])` then you will need to declare `s` as follows:

```
char *s[] = {"one","two","three","four"};
int r;
r = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);  // Now r will equal 4
```

Comment: Though, it's better to not declare size of array in this case - declaring it shouldn't cause an issue - s[4] to s[9] would be null pointers.

Comment: No not in this case. Take a `2D` array `s[row][col]`. When your convert to pointer notation `*(s[row] + col)` as done here, you are creating a pointer to `10 strings` with `*s[10]`. While `4-9` may be empty `sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0])` will still return `10` instead of `4`. By declaring `*s[]` you let the compiler fill in the number of rows from the designation of string literals. (thank you, you helped catch a mistake in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

`char (*p)[10]` is pointer to `char[10]`, not `char *s[10]` (array of 10's pointer to `char`)
There is a need to change the `main` and if `void print_2d(char (*p)[10], int r)` is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_2d(char (*p)[10], int r){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);
}

int main(){
    char s[][10]={"one","two","three","four"};
    int r;
    r=sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
    print_2d(s,r);
    return 0;
}
```